# What is this "wvm" file, and can I get rid of it?

Tags: file-management, nexus-7

I have a Nexus 7 running Jelly Bean. Using the [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) program, I was examining the contents of part of the internal drive and found this:

`/Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files/Movies/bWF0dGhldy5ob2x0QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ/framework_LFL4UnYvaGE.wvm` (2.82 GB, last modified 18 Jul 2012, 7:59 PM)

In another directory (adjacent to `bWF0dGhldy5ob2x0QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ`), there's a **subtitles** directory which contains two files:

`LFL4UnYvaGE.cc` (264 bytes) and `LFL4UnYvaGE.en.cc` (129 KB), both modified on the same day (18 Jul, but earlier in the day at 5:57 PM).

[image]

As you can see, the **.wvm** file is very large. I tried renaming its parent **Movies** folder to **Movies2** to see if it broke anything and so far it doesn't seem to matter. I tried copying it to my Mac but it says it is unable to copy the file (yet it can copy the parent folder(s) okay). And I don't currently have any movies (that I know of) saved to my tablet either from the Play store or copied over from my computer.

What does this file do, and would it be safe to delete it (and the associated subtitles) to save space?

Comment: Could be the free movie, transformer or something that comes with Nexus 7.

Comment: .wvm is a DRM encoded video file (WideVine media file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These files are for the *Transformers: Dark of the Moon* film which was included promotionally with your Nexus 7.  The movie was not, at least in my case, pre-installed on your device, as it takes a considerable amount of your available storage space (especially if you have an 8GB unit!).

I'm guessing you must at some point have unknowingly hit the small 'button' on the video telling it to download the film for offline use.

---

The first thing that came to my mind was, that this may be a WebM video file (Matroska container + VP8 video stream + Vorbis audio stream). It would have made sense. But feeding the file to MediaInfo looks like this:

```
$ mediainfo Downloads/framework_BpAYRcyW2_A.wvm
General
Complete name                            : Downloads/framework_BpAYRcyW2_A.wvm
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 2.73 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 34mn
Overall bit rate                         : 2 532 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Duration                                 : 2h 34mn
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 536 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive

Audio
ID                                       : 192 (0xC0)
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                           : Version 4
Format profile                           : LC
Muxing mode                              : ADTS
Duration                                 : 2h 34mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable / Variable / Variable
Minimum bit rate                         : 190 Kbps / 190 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 231 Kbps / 231 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy

Menu
```

An AVC video stream and AAC audio stream, is what one would expect from a regular MP4, but MPEG-PS format (PS = program stream) is unusual. This is how a regular MP4 looks in MediaInfo:

```
$ mediainfo .miro/Movies/FLOSS-Weekly/floss0222_h264m_864x480_500.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : .miro/Movies/FLOSS-Weekly/floss0222_h264m_864x480_500.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 282 MiB
Duration                                 : 1h 5mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 605 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf54.3.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1h 5mn
Bit rate                                 : 500 Kbps
Width                                    : 864 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.040
Stream size                              : 233 MiB (83%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 120 r2164 da19765
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x131 / me=umh / subme=6 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=2 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=60 / keyint_min=31 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=500 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / vbv_maxrate=1500 / vbv_bufsize=6000 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 5mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 96.0 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 1 500 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 44.7 MiB (16%)
Language                                 : English
```

The file [from the Nexus 7] even  plays for a few seconds in VLC and in MPlayer, but then I get error messages. So either the format is not yet supported or it's sort of encrypted.

Comment: you get the error message because the file is DRM encrypted, but all DRM files have the first 10 seconds unencrypted - hence you being able to play them

Answer (score 10):

WVM is a video file that has been encrypted using the Widevine (now Google) DRM platform.
The first 10 seconds are not encrypted, that is why you can see it in VLC.

Answer (score 3):

A wvm file is not the same as a wmv, the wvm is a video downloaded from Google Play Movies and is a type of MPEG-4 video file. It is currently unable to be opened by anything other than the Google Play Movies app because of the DRM properties surrounding the file.

Answer (score 0):

All my wvm files that I found were copies of Google Play TV/movies that I'd downloaded previously and thought I'd deleted off the storage afterwards. I got rid of about 4gb of those files by using a file manager app and searching the device for wvm files.

Answer (score -1):

WMV and WVM not same. İf you download some film in the android market inside this film format WVM. İf you want to check you can.this file inside ( STORAGE - SDCARD0 - ANDROİD - DATA - com.google.android.videos - FİLES - MOVİES -Yi5zZW43OUBnbWFpbC5jb20 ) All this film this folder inside. You can delete if you want.

Answer (score -3):

WMV stands for [Windows Media Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmv) -- so what you've found very likely is a Video-file with subtitles. It could be a demo video shipped together with the application in whichs directory it resides ([Google Play Movies & TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.videos)). I'd say it should be safe to delete it -- but I would first try doing so via the app itself to be sure (there you also could first play it to see what it is about -- plus deleting it from there would ensure all connected data is removed as well). In the worst case, you may need to re-install the app.

Comment: Is **WMV** the same as **WVM** then? (And there's no videos that appear in the Play Movies & TV app. That's what I thought too, though.)

Comment: Ouch, got me! I thought it was a misspelling on your side (and due to the subtitles I didn't check a second time) -- the screenshot has it WVM, too. Looks like *they* messed with the names (see [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1668488). Heck, even a google search asks me "did you mean WMV"...

Comment: PS: From the context I take it they switch the letters for DRMd videos. Could it be you purchased some video?

Comment: Here's another one: http://www.droidrzr.com/index.php/topic/1899-re-play-downloaded-google-play-movies/ -- and yeah, pretty sure it's a movie file, and almost sure it's a DRMd WMV :)

Comment: Well, the Nexus 7 came with a free Transformers movie purchase. I downloaded it then I removed it when I was finished (I tapped the pin icon) a while ago. So just now I long-tapped the movie and touched "Remove from Device." It no longer appears in my Play Movies app. Yet now, and even before, "Settings" said the Movies app was taking only 6.12 MB. But the file transfer program still shows the same files there. And thanks for that link; I wonder how to extract it. (The movie isn't rented; it's purchased, and I prefer to liberate my data.)

Comment: Quick update: I deleted the files in question with the File Transfer program. Of course it won't let me copy the DRM'ed file to my computer. Perhaps for another topic, I'd like to learn how to get the file off my device and onto my computer (for safe keeping).

Comment: Another topic, for sure -- and it has to do with root. Which may make some DRM stuff no longer working (I've read the servers block rooted devices, which then would apply to this app as well). I don't care, as I never take any DRM'd stuff (I also do not DRM my books even when directly offered). Things I've bought I own and should be able to use where I want.